# Trying to install cartalyst/data-grid

Tags: php, datagrid, laravel-4, composer-php, cartalyst-sentry

I'm just wondering if this has happened to anyone and how they've been able to solve it.

I'm trying to install data-grid from Cartalyst, following [this-manual](https://cartalyst.com/manual/data-grid).

Anyway. When i get to the step where i have to either install or update, command prompt shows me these errors or messages.

If I run "composer install":

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json.
You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

If i run "composer update" when data-grid version is 2.0.*:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package cartalyst/data-grid could not be found in any versio
n, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common
 problems.
```

If i run "composer update" with any other version it just says it couldn't find the repository.

Just to complement this thread, here's my composer.json.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "cartalyst/data-grid": "dev-master",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "dev-develop"
},
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "http://packages.cartalyst.com"
}
],
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I would appreciate some help with this. Or at least suggesting another data-grid extension that isn't phpGrid or jQGrid because I already used those and didn't like them. But I do want a grid that is sortable and has integrated search.

Comment: DATA-GRID BY CARTALYST requires paid subscription https://cartalyst.com/manual/data-grid/3.0#installation

Answer (score -1):

Try to change "minimum-stability" from "stable" to "dev" and append "prefer-stable":true
But notice the data-grid require cartalyst subscription (it costs $75 per 3 month)